# What is the different between AWS::LAMBDA and AWS::LAMBDA::FUNCTION in xray?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-xray

I enable labmda xray on AWS and I am able to see the service map on xray console. But what I don't understand is the different between AWS::LAMBDA and AWS::LAMBDA::FUNCTION. If you look at below screenshot, you will see that my lambda `requestTransactionhandler` show in two section. One is `AWS:Lambda` the other is `AWS::Lambda::Function`. Each of them have a different latency. What is the different between them?

And there are 2 seconds more latency on AWS::Lambda so how can I improve it?

[image]

Comment: `AWS::Lambda` is the AWS Lambda service itself, while `AWS::Lambda::Function` is your actual function that you developed.

Comment: why is there 2 sec latency on AWS:Lambda?

Comment: Maybe it was the start up time of your function? Not sure, thus I can't give you full answer.

Comment: If it is AWS lambda service, that means the latency has nothing to do with my lambda right?

Comment: Does this happen all the time, or only for the first execution of your function? Usually the first invocation is slow due to so called "cold start".

Comment: It is 2 seconds at the first time but around 1 second on average. I understand code start is a performance but I don't expect it to be second. It makes sense for 200 ms.

Comment: Marcin is right about the two components of the lambda service and the function itself.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

X-ray divides the function in two parts

1. Functions's startup overhead represented with AWS::Lambda
2. Functions's execution time represented with AWS::Lambda::Function

These two parts of function are the two subsegments created by XRay.